# How to post table data without refreshing my view after removing a record?

Tags: html, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am writing a movie app that allows you to rent movies (similar to Redbox). I have a CheckOut cart view containing a table. Each table row has a remove button which uses AJAX to delete  element in the view and also update the SQL database that the app works with. After removing any items from the cart, the user should be able to click 'purchase' and process the items that were left in the cart, all without needing to refresh the page.

I have an Order model containing a list of OrderDetails. Each OrderDetails item has information about a movie. It is data from OrderDetails list that the table is populated with.

The issue comes in when I remove items from cart and try to post the form with the values in the table. My CheckOut HttpPost controller method receives the model, but the OrderDetail list still has the item count it originally had before I removed items from cart. Logically, there is no data bound to the properties since I deleted the hidden  tags I had in each record.

Because the list contains elements I don't need, processing the list results in garbage data going into the database.

I tried to simply remove the garbage elements within my CheckOut HttpPost method before it begins processing the list. This worked great but I don't want to have to remove anything in the CheckOut method after posting the form. I'm expecting the list to not contain the elements.

CheckOut POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CheckOut(Order order)
{         
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return View("CheckOut", order);
    }

    foreach (var orderDetailObj in order.OrderDetailsList)
    {
        _checkOutService.StoreMoviesInOrder(GetConnectionString(), order.OrderId, orderDetailObj);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("PurchaseSummary", new { Id = order.OrderId });
}
```

CheckOut.cshtml view:

```
@model MovieContract.Order

...

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderDetailsList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="btnRemove" class="removeButton" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(this, '@Model.CartId', @Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmId)" />
        </td>
        <td hidden>
            <input asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.AddedToCart" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.AddedToCart" hidden />
        </td>
        <td hidden>
            <input asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmId" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmId" hidden />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmName" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmName" hidden />
            @Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmName
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.GenreName" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.GenreName" hidden />
            @Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.GenreName
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.PricePerDay" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.PricePerDay" class="pricePerDay" hidden />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.PricePerDay)
        </td>
        <td hidden>
            <input asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.AmountOnHand" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.AmountOnHand" hidden />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

As for AJAX, I simply have an AJAX function that calls a post controller method. The method deletes the appropriate item from the database and returns NoContent();. Upon success, AJAX deletes the desired row from the view.

I expect that by the time I reach the CheckOut HttpPost method, the parameter object's list property will contain less elements if I had decided to remove any from the cart. I don't want to have to refresh the whole page to rebuild my model each time I remove an item from the cart.

Comment: You can use `Ajax Helper in MVC` refer this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-ajax-helper/)

Comment: @jishansiddique I am unsure how this will help me since I already use AJAX to successfully remove table row in my view and the record in my database. What's left is to remove the empty element in my list before I post the form. I'm guessing I should be something more than just removing the <tr> element and updating the database, but I can't figure out what that could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo :

1. View

   ```
   @model AjaxDeleteItem.Models.Order

   <div>
   <form method="post" asp-action="CheckOut">
   <table class="table" id="table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th></th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderDetailsList.Count; i++)
           {
               <tr class="count">
                   <td>
                       <input type="button" name="btnRemove" class="removeButton" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(this, @Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Id)" />
                   </td>
                   <td >
                       <input class="FilmId" asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmId" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmId" />
                   </td>
                   <td >
                       <input class="FilmName" asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmName" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.FilmName" />

                   </td >
                   <td>
                       <input class="GenreName" asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.GenreName" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.GenreName" />

                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input class="PricePerDay" asp-for="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.PricePerDay" value="@Model.OrderDetailsList[i].Movie.PricePerDay"  />

                   </td>
               </tr>
           }
       </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>

   </div>


   @section Scripts
   {
   <script>
   function Remove(obj,id) {
   $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "/orders/deleteorderitem?id="+id,
       success: function () {
           $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
           var count = $(" tbody tr").length;
           var i = 0;
           $("tbody tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                   if (i < count)
                   {
                       row.find("input[class=FilmId]").attr("name", "OrderDetailsList[" + i + "].Movie.FilmId");
                       row.find("input[class=FilmName]").attr("name", "OrderDetailsList[" + i + "].Movie.FilmName");
                       row.find("input[class=GenreName]").attr("name", "OrderDetailsList[" + i + "].Movie.GenreName");
                       row.find("input[class=PricePerDay]").attr("name", "OrderDetailsList[" + i + "].Movie.PricePerDay");
                       i++;
                   }                       
               });                       
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("Fail to delete");
       }
   });
   }
   </script>
   }
   ```

2.Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteOrderItem(int id)
    {
        var orderdetail = await _context.OrderDetails.FindAsync(id);
        _context.OrderDetails.Remove(orderdetail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CheckOut(Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            return View("Details", order.CartId);
        }

        //the stuff you want
    }
```

3. Result :
[image]

Comment: I've implemented the solution and it works perfectly. This is exactly what I wanted. I will dissect the code and figure out what it is doing to make things work. Thank you so much for your effort.