# How to keep table items removed after refreshing a post method?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This issue is closely related to the code and problem I had in an older post of mine: [How to post table data without refreshing my view after removing a record?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58635913/12300287).

I have a CheckOut GET method that builds an Order model and returns it to the CheckOut View. I also have a CheckOut POST method that processes the POSTed Order model after filling in additional fields in the CheckOut View and submitting the form.

I run into a problem when the ModelState.IsValid == false. When that happens, I return the Order to the checkout view and display the error. However, if at that point I remove items from the the table in the CheckOut View and refresh the page, the items I had removed return to the table.

This doesn't happen if I remove items from my table and and refresh the page before having anything POSTed. The reason for this is, of course, because the CheckOut GET method rebuilds the Order model from the updated tables in the database.

Things I've tried:

1. If ModelState.IsValid==false in CheckOut POST, redirect to CheckOut GET action. That fixed the issue, but introduced a new one where if the form was filled out incorrectly, the view did display form errors to the user. I am guessing this is because ModelState was cleared.
2. Another potential solution is to rebuild the Order model each time I POST the CheckOut View. However, I don't want to be rebuilding the Order again. I am already doing that in the GET method.

CheckOut GET method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CheckOut(string Id)
{
    Order order = new Order();

    order.CartId = Id;

    //populate order object's parameters

    return View(order);
}
```

CheckOut POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CheckOut(Order order)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return View("CheckOut", order);
    }

    //process the order object

    return RedirectToAction("PurchaseSummary", new { Id = order.OrderId });
}
```

My CheckOut View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Dp3.png
If I were to remove an item from the table and refresh the View without POSTing it again, the CheckOut POST method would run and the item would return to the table. I expect the table to not contain the item when I refresh.

EDIT: I put FormCollection collection in HttpPost and, in the case of refreshing the page, the old items are still in the collection.

Comment: I looked at the previous question, you might want to look at using PartialView instead. That way, your javascript wouldn't need to keep a record of your class name which could get problematic when you update your app later.

Comment: @the_lotus Thank you for the comment. When you say JavaScript needing to keep a record of my class name, do you mean what I have hardcoded here?: row.find("input[class=filmId]").attr("name", "OrderDetailsList[" + i + "].Movie.FilmId");

Comment: Yes, your delete method could return a partial view containing all the table information and update the table with that. Can your verify that the HTML is ok and doesn't contain trace of the old record and that the index are in the right order?

Comment: The partial view sounds like a more proper way to do it, which I may implement. I would still like to find out what is going on here because I lack the understanding. I checked my HTML code and all traces of removed records are gone and the indexes are in order.

Comment: Then I don't know why order contains trace of the old item since it doesn't even exists in the posted data. Maybe put a FormCollection collection in the HttpPost and see if the old item is there. If it's not, I don't know how it gets populated unless it from the session somehow.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Just to make sure I was clear, it is only when I refresh the page right after removing items from the cart that the POST method runs and still contains all the items in the model. If I were to remove some items and fill out the form correctly (https://i.imgur.com/gbl3kSH.png), and then click the purchase, the model in the POST method would not contain those removed items.